# Execute sh file with Russian or Chines Chars - Saved as UTF-8 or Unicode

Tags: bash, encoding, character-encoding, locale

I have a file which has some russian chars in. Below is the content of by sh file.

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i "s/\bVAR1\b/Привет, как ты/g" file1.txt
```

When i save this file i had to save this as UTF-8 or Unicode format as i have some Unicode format characters in the file and i will loose those if i save as ANSI. Once i save the file , when i use the file command i get the below

```
bash-4.1$ file test.sh
test.sh: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) English text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

Question : how can I make this as executable shell script file? I get the below if my file has only English chars

```
bash-4.1$ file test2.sh
test2.sh: POSIX shell script text executable
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I copied your script, with similar results, but when I corrected the first line, as @KamilMaciorowski indicates, then everything works fine. Indeed, it works without the correction (giving an error on the first line), despite the `file` output.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I got the script work. Had to avoid BOM chars and set fileformat=unix if the file was edited using any windows editor tools